# Best cheap basic analogue audio mixer?

Tags: audio, mixer, purchase-advice

I'm basically looking for a device that allows for multiple (at least two, maybe three or four) stereo RCA inputs and a single stereo RCA output. There needs to be a fader on each stereo input. A crossfader is optional and I do not need any EQ options.

This device needs to be as cheap as possible, and is simple to mix together multiple inputs in a home setup to avoid me having to unplug/replug various devices and changing the volume to match the device. It's not for professional mixing.

I'm struggling to find something that is cheap, as all I can find is expensive DJ mixers with EQ options, whereas I require something cheap and basic.

I can't find anything suitable. I found some things but they are not cheap or have the wrong inputs. Hope you can help me out here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you could buy a (2nd hand) behringer mixer and some rca>jack adapters: http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/UB1002FX.aspx

not a perfect but a cheap solution

Comment: Behringer mixer get broken very fast (my colleagues and my opinion).

Comment: I agrre with @Arnoud.  For the described situation, a Behringer like this (although not pretty looking) will get the job done.  I've seen these used all over the place, and for a reliable price-point (read: you get what you pay for) product, Behringer's probably the best there is out there.  I used their VMX DJ mixer for a long time and as long as you treat the gear with care, it's been reliable.

Comment: Hi Tobias, i agree that Behringers products are not top class units (and especially the lower priced ones). However this is a fairly simple unit, that won't be used in a demanding environment or tweaked heavily. Or are you saying that break down by themselves? If that's the case I would look elsewhere for a solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something legit, you're probably out of luck. I've made this search many times before and came up dry. Lots of splitters, but no mixers.

Your best bet is probably [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Altoids-Tin-18-Stereo-Mixer/). It's a super basic "rat's nest" electronics project, and you should be able to pick up the components for pretty cheap. Any RadioShack will carry them, and you might even be able to scum the wire and resistors off of a friend to bring the cost down even more, if you hang out with anybody like that. The only real catch is that **you need to know how to solder.** If you can't, try to find somebody who can help you.

Comment: Great fun. Only thing it's missing is the faders, which is a shame.

Comment: If you're electronics-savvy, it might not be too hard to toss some rheostats into the mix.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your budget, but i would go for a very durable small device. Did you check the Allen Heath ZED Mixers?

http://www.thomann.de/de/allenheath_zed10.htm

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question it was never really answered fully.

The Rolls MX51s is a simple mixer with 3 x RCA in and 1 x RCA out, stereo.  And it's only $55.  So that probably meets the requirements.

https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/868713-REG/Rolls_MX51s_Mini_Mix_2.html

Comment: I would look at the Rolls also, I have used them in small applications and they work really well. Rolls is high quality.